# Find a string in a list of substrings (google sheets)

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of substrings like this (list 1)

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
```

Then I have a list of strings like this (list 2)

```
ABCLKAKJDAKSDJ
DEFADLKASDKAS
GHIASDKASLDK
```

I want to find the list of substrings for each item in the list of strings, with an output like this:

```
ABCLKAKJDAKSDJ   ABC
DEFADLKASDKAS   DEF
GHIASDKASLDK  GHI
```

You can assume that the strings in list 1 will only be found in the front of strings in list 2.

Comment: So you want to find the string in list 1 within list 2, and then print the string next to list 2?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
=query(arrayformula(split(flatten(iferror(C1:C3 &"~"& A1:A4 & "~" & SEARCH( A1:A4,transpose(C1:C3)))),"~",false)),"select Col1,Col2 where Col3=1")
```

List 1 in A

List 2 in C

Formula in E1

[image]